# MATLAB and mechanics (physics mostly) [part II]

Tags: matlab, physics, simulink

Resume form [part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880545/matlab-and-mechanics-mostly-physics)

Basic scheme representing the system:
[image: system]

We assume that coupling of the two shafts is done with a clutch

Equations:

```
• J1*dw1/dt + Td(w12)+Ts(phi12) = T1;
• J2*dw2/dt - Td(w12) -Ts(phi12) = T2;
where w1 = dphi1/dt, 
    w2 = dphi2/dt, 
    phi12 = phi1 - phi2
    w12 = w1 - w2
    Td(w12) = c12 * w12
    Ts(phi12) = ks * phi12
c12 and ks are some coefficients
• dphi12/dt = w12
• dw12/dt = T1/J1 - T2/J2 - Td(w12)/Jeq - Ts(phi12)/Jeq

ccr = 2*Jeq*wn
wn = sqrt(ks/Jeq)
Jeq = (J1*J2)/(J1+J2)
T1(t) = T0*1(t), T0 = 1 T2(t) = 0
J1+J2 = 10 wn = 100 rad/s c12 = 0 Ts(phi12) = ks*phi12
```

My second task is to plot how nonlinear clutch affects the rotational inertia.

Given :

```
T1(t) = T0*1(t), T0 = 1, T2(t) = 0,
J1 = J2 = 5, c12 = 0, wn = 100,
Ts(phi12) = k1*phi12 + k2*(phi12)^3
k20 = 10e14, k2 = [10e-6 10e-5 10e-4 10e-3 10e-2 10e-1 10e0 10e1 10e2 10e3 10e4]
```

I need to plot the `Tsmax/T0 = f(log(k2/k20))`;

So far my progress is:

MATLAB code

```
T2 = 0;
J1 = 5;
J2 = J1;
wn = 100;
Jz = J1.*J2/(J1+J2);
ckr = 2.*Jz*wn;
ks = (wn^2)*Jz;
c12 = 0;
k20 = 10e14;
k2 = [10e-6 10e-5 10e-4 10e-3 10e-2 10e-1 10e0 10e1 10e2 10e3 10e4];
Tsmax = zeros(size(k2));
k2a = 0;
plpl = zeros(size(k2));
k1 = 1;
sim ('model_2');

for ii=1:length(k2)
    k2a = k2(ii);
    sim ('model_2');
    Tsmax(ii) = max(Ts);
    plpl(ii) = log(k2a/k20);
end
figure()
    plot(plpl,Tsmax)  
   grid on
```

which yields

[image: matlab_plot_1]

and Simulink model:

[image: simulink]

Well, I'm kind of sure my plot is not what it should be like.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The question is what did i do wrong, and if anyone can find the mistake.

Comment: The only problem you've identified is "i'm kind of sure my plot is not what it should be like". We're not here to debug your code for you, and your question is very vague. What should the plot look like? Do you know it's not correct?

Comment: I have mentioned that i have totally no clue what to do with the system, I hope someone with more experience in physics could take a look, therefore.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden but you are here at StackOverflow, we deal with programming questions. Your problem is the physics, so maybe you find easier help at [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @thewaywewalk thanks dude for the recom. I m still pretty new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points/suggestions:

- It seems that you parameterise your Simulink model with `K2a` (unless I can't see very well from the screenshot), but it's not defined anywhere. You define `k2a` in your code, but MATLAB is case-sensitive so it's not the same as as `K2a`.
- Your `Fcn1` block doesn't do anything, you can get rid of it.

Apart from that, I don't really see anything wrong with what you have done, and we don't know what your plot should look like, so we can't really help you more than that I'm afraid.

**EDIT**:

I think that's what your plot is supposed to look like. I tried it in Octave, just using MATLAB code & the ode solver (no Simulink) with `logspace` so that I have 50 data points logarithmically space between `10^(-6)` and `10^4`, and got something very similar.

[image]

I think you are hitting numerical stiffness issues with larger values of `k2` so I would suggest using `ode15s` and a max step size of `1e-4`. This may take a bit longer to run, but you might avoid numerical issues when the system is numerically stiff.

Comment: The gain is set properly to k2a, otherwise it would not be working at all. Furthermore I am not sure that the nonlinearity of the system is actually behaving such chaotic.

Comment: As I said, I wasn't 100% sure from looking at the screenshot, it was just a suggestion. You can try adding more data points for `k2` using `logspace`, and also tweak your solver settings in Simulink. You may be encountering some numerical stiffness issues depending on the value of `k2`. What solver/settings are you currently using?

Comment: I am using ODE 23t with default settings  which is pretty decent in visualizing the Ts.

Comment: I tried the logspace with 150 points but the curve looks even more abstract.

Comment: See my edited answer. I think your plot is basically correct, but you are hitting numerical stiffness issues with higher values of `k2`.

Comment: It looks really better this way. Is there a way u are able to tell that a function is stiff or you re relying on your experience?

Comment: There isn't a magical recipe for numerical stiffness, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation and http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/stiff-differential-equations.html. Fortunately, in the case of mechanical systems, it more or less translates to mechanical stiffness: here you have two (potentially low) masses/inertia coupled with (potentially high) stiffness and no/little damping. My suggestion is to use `logspace(-6,4)` for `k2` and `ode15s` (although `ode23t` may also work) with a max step size of `1e-4`.